# Append in real time based on values in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, socket.io

So, I am currently appending to my web page and or removing from it based on values stored in an array.

But in order for them to appear I need to reload the page, but I need it all to happen on the fly without reloading the page. So as soon as I append I can see it, same goes for when I remove it.

I have been using socket.io server side code to try and do it but I have had mixed results. Am not too experienced with socket.io and still trying to get to grips with it.

Am literally just trying to emit data based on what is stored in the array chanArr in real time by appending it to the table.

**app.js file**

This is my server side code for socket.io, the function updateSip is what is emitting the data back to the client side.

```
var ari = require('ari-client');
var util = require('util');
var chanArr = [];
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
server = require('http').createServer(app),
io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

//ARI client
ari.connect('http://localhost:8088', 'asterisk', 'asterisk', clientLoaded);

function clientLoaded(err, client) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    // find or create a holding bridges
    var bridge = null;
    client.bridges.list(function (err, bridges) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }

        bridge = bridges.filter(function (candidate) {
                return candidate.bridge_type === 'mixing';
            })[0];

        if (bridge) {
            console.log(util.format('Using bridge %s', bridge.id));
        } else

            client.bridges.create({
                type : 'mixing'
            }, function (err, newBridge) {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }

                bridge = newBridge;
                console.log(util.format('Created bridge %s', bridge.id));
            });
    }
    });

    // handler for StasisStart event
    function stasisStart(event, channel) {
        console.log(util.format(
                'Channel %s just entered our application, adding it to bridge %s',
                channel.name,
                bridge.id));

        channel.answer(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }

            bridge.addChannel({
                channel : channel.id
            }, function (err) {
                var id = chanArr.push(channel.name)
                    updateSip();
                console.log("User: " + channel.name);
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }

                //If else statement to start music for first user entering channel, music will stop once more than 1 enters the channel.
                if (chanArr.length <= 1) {
                    bridge.startMoh(function (err) {
                        if (err) {
                            throw err;
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    bridge.stopMoh(function (err) {
                        if (err) {
                            throw err;
                        }
                    });
                }

            });
        });
    }

    // handler for StasisEnd event
    function stasisEnd(event, channel) {
        console.log(util.format(
                'Channel %s just left our application', channel.name));
        console.log(channel.name);

        var index = chanArr.indexOf(channel.name);
        chanArr.splice(index, 1);
        updateSip();
    }
    client.on('StasisStart', stasisStart);
    client.on('StasisEnd', stasisEnd);
    client.start('bridge-hold');
    }

    //Socket.io logic here
    server.listen(3009, function () {
        console.log('listening on *:3009');
    });

    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.sendfile(__dirname + "/testPage.html");
    });

    io.sockets.on('connection', function () {
        updateSip();
    });

    io.sockets.on('updateSip', function () {
        console.log('Being called!')
        updateSip();
    });

    function updateSip() {
        io.sockets.emit('sip', chanArr);
    }
```

**test.js**

Client side JQuery and socket.io code and where am appending elements to the web page.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var socket = io.connect();
    var $sip = $('#sip');
    socket.on('sip', function (data) {
        var sip = '';
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            sip += data[i]
        if(sip){
        $sip.append('<tr>\
                                    <td>' + sip + '</td>\
                                    <td><input type="checkbox" data-on="Voice" data-off="Muted" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger"></td>\
                                    <td><button class="btn btn-default kick" id="kick" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" type="submit">Kick</button></td>\
                                    </tr>');
        }
        else{
            $sip.append('Currently no extensions');
        }
        sip = '';
        }

    });
});
```

**testPage.html**

What I am appending too.

```
            <div class="secondary-bridge">
<h3 class="conf-head">Conference call:</h3>
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Extension</th>
            <th>Mute</th>
            <th>Kick</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id ="sip">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**EDIT:**
So at the moment, I have to refresh the page so the page runs the updateSip function, to then emit and display the new values which have been appended, every time I add, or remove a value from the array which handles what to display I have to refresh the page.

Page loads -> Array[]-> Call, inserts value in array-> Array['SIP-448']-> Reload page ->Can now see it appended.

I am trying to get it to work so I never have to refresh.

First thing I tried before asking for some advice was the method @show-me-the-code suggested and the following happens, it does do kinda what I want it to do but after 1 value, it breaks, and values when they are removed from the array also still stay displayed on the webpage:

**1 Value**
[image: 1 Value Added to array]

**More than 1 value**
[image: More than 1 value in array]

When I refresh the page it then goes to this:

[image: Then Refresh the page]

When I then try to remove a value from the array it then appends the previous value, once I refresh the page there is only one value which is the on which should remain.

Which is my big issue I dont know why its acting the way it is currently.

Comment: I think you must check out WEBSOCKETS in this case

Comment: Is it not possible for me to simply emit the data from Socket.io server side to the client side? Considering its used for real time web applications?

Comment: Then the only option is to keep polling from the server to check the object status at the backend and frontend match..

Comment: And I was suggesting WEBSOCKETS in Javascript. not the socket.io

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal OP is using websockets, that's what the socket.io lib is for. At a glance the code looks fine and should probably work. Do you get any errors in developer console and/or node?

Comment: @Studento919 you are calling the `updateSip` function (where `sip` is emmited) only when user comes to site. i.e. on connection. You should call that function when your actions also get processed. i.e. some data computation so that on every request ( here your `addChannel` function ) you can get the desired output.

Comment: I think its the string concat issue where in jquery the op is trying to append the tr's and td's using `\`.. I think there is a string break somewhere..

Comment: @HarshMakani I tried that already, it works for the first value in the array, when a 2nd is added it adds it but also adds the previous value, and also does not remove the values if they are removed from the array.

Comment: Your `app.js` code has unmatched brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I would do. On the server side where your `chanArr` changes (elements are added or removed), trigger an `emit('sip', chanArr)` call.

```
// right after adding channel to the array
chanArr.push(channel.name);
updateSip();

// also after removing it from the array if it is in different function
chanArr.splice(index, 1);
updateSip();
```

Comment: First thing I did when coming up for a solution was this, but it works for the first value in the array, when a 2nd is added it adds it but also adds the previous value, and also does not remove the values if they are removed from the array.

Comment: Of course, because you are sending the entire array every time. Why not just send the value (`channel.name`) when it is added or removed, and then append or delete from the client accordingly? That will make sure you only append or delete one row at a time.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you want to update data of your server to your clientside.

The problem with your code is that you only call the function `updateSip()` on client-connection. If you want to update it somewhen else you have to provide more code to your `app.js`

You might, for instance, create an event listener like

```
io.sockets.on('updateSip', function () {
  updateSip();
});
```

and on your clientside you might create a function like

```
function updateSip() {
    socket.emit('updateSip');  
},
```

that way your server answers with the information you need if you call the function `updateSip()` in your `test.js`

Comment: Yeah, you pretty much nailed it on the head and am aware that it only gets called on connection, as a newbie to socket.io its still all a learning process. I tried something like what you sugessted but I dont think am calling the function or something, the result stays the same. I also tried calling the updateSip function at the addChannel segment but it kinda does and doesn't work. You can refer to a comment above as to why

Comment: since it could be that `io.sockets.on('connect',..` fires before `ari.connect` it could be that your `chanArr` is not up to date. Try it like @show-me-the-code suggests

Comment: if you check my updated question, I already tried that method and the results of what happens are there.

Comment: the formatting of your code seems really bad. that way its hard to get a good overview of it. well it seems like you forgot to provide the function `stasisEnd` to your code. I guess you want `var index = chanArr.indexOf(channel.name);
    chanArr.splice(index, 1);` to be inside the `stasisEnd`-function

Comment: I tried to reduce the amount of code to look at and it is wrapped inside stasis end. Ill update question with full code of that file.